# jQuery Ajax placing random "jQuery111201xxx" into string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a booking system that utilizes FullCalendar; though that part should be irrelevant. My problem is that upon saving an appointment, a 'notes' field I have created very occasionally has this strange string inserted into it, generally at a random point in the string. Here is the latest example:

*Has this been changedjQuery1112010047650896012783_1444929292744 with Rich- finishing sleeve off.bringing deposit in on saturday. told him space isnt secure.*

As you can see, there is a totally out of place "jQuery1112010047650896012783_1444929292744" placed in the middle of the note. I can't find anything about this online (mainly because I have no idea what terms I'd use to find it). It must be related to jQuery, considering the string.

I am using jQuery v1.11.2 - obviously the string looks like a long version number.

Why is my ajax request seemingly succeeding, but placing this message in the middle of the sent string? I cannot replicate this issue at all, especially this time since it was another user who managed to cause it.

The function that fetches/prepares/sends data looks like this:

```js
function postForm(content, action, update) {
    loader('show');
    var popup = content.parent();
    var children = content.find(".input");
    var data = {}
    var elements = [];
    data['elements'];
    $( children ).each(function() {
        var child = {};
        child['name'] = $(this).attr('data-name');
        if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
            child['value'] = $(this).is(":checked");
        } else {
            child['value'] = $(this).val();
        }
        elements.push(child);
    });
    data.elements = elements;
    data.request = action;
    dataPost = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(dataPost);
    ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/?page=ajax",
    data: dataPost,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        loader('hide');
        console.log(response);
        if (update) {
            $(update.element).load(update.url+" "+update.element+" > *");
            checkError = doExtra(response, update.extra);
        }
        if (checkError == false) {
            popup.fadeOut();
        }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

The note section is just a textarea with the class 'input' (which is looped through and fetched).

[image: The notes field]

I don't think there will be a solution for the exact problem, however, **I'm looking for an explanation for the modification of the string**. The application works perfectly, except for this very rare case.

Comment: `generally at a random point in the string` - does this random point usually look like it could've been a question mark originally?

Comment: @JaromandaX That's a good point; I can't confirm this for sure but that's possible. I've tried adding other notes with "?"s, but I'm not getting the issue..

Comment: what you could do is use the netework tab in the developer tools of your favourite browser to see if it's the client sending that string, or maybe the server is misinterpreting the "input"?

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right. Adding a row of question marks causes it to hang, and not get a response, but still send the request with this string inserted. Do you know any fixes?

Comment: `dataPost = JSON.stringify(data);` this looks odd. usually one does not need to do this especially with jQueery $.ajax ... usually one would use (with your variable names) `data: data,`

Comment: @JaromandaX This doesn't work, probably due to my server-side code expecting JSON; however, I found a solution with some searching, I added jsonp: false and question marks are no longer replaced. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: `this doesn't work, probably due to my server-side code expecting JSON;` - I must admit I don't know how jqueery works with POST data, when dataType is 'json' - I thought jquery handled the jsonifying for you :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question marks (??) are replaced with a jQuery time stamp. To fix, I had to add jsonp: false to the parameters. Final ajax:

```js
 ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/?page=ajax",
    data: dataPost,
    dataType: 'json',
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(response) {
        loader('hide');
        console.log(response);
        if (update) {
            $(update.element).load(update.url+" "+update.element+" > *");
            checkError = doExtra(response, update.extra);
        }
        if (checkError == false) {
            popup.fadeOut();
        }
    }
  });
```